# VBA Dynamically select a single column reference on a static set of multiple rows?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dynamic-programming

I am working on creating a report for someone in my organization. The report has multiple scenarios that they want to test by copying a single scenario and pasting it into a column that then will do a calculation. The parts they copy are not in a constant order, ie it is multiple selections (E30:E34 , E37:E39 , etc.) But they are all in the same column (E for instance) and the row number reference on the multiple selections will always be the same for each scenario.  I only need to change the column reference from E all the way to AW (possibly more in the future). I was thinking maybe there is way to set up a cell above each scenario to use as a "check box" that the vba code could look for to know to use that column reference. Or possibly just an entry box to type the column letter they want. I have a loop code written and working to run through the multiple selections and copy paste I will post below. I just need a way to dynamically change the column reference in the rArray (E to F or G or H etc.) I hope this is possible. Thanks!

This is the code I have to copy and paste the selected ranges:

```
Sub CopyScenario()

    Dim rArray(1 To 22) As Range
    Dim tArray(1 To 22) As Range

'Set up ranges for selected scenario

    Set rArray(1) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E30:E34")
    Set rArray(2) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E37:E39")
    Set rArray(3) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E41")
    Set rArray(4) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E43:E44")
    Set rArray(5) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E47:E50")
    Set rArray(6) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E52")
    Set rArray(7) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E54")
    Set rArray(8) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E56:E57")
    Set rArray(9) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E59:E60")
    Set rArray(10) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E64:E66")
    Set rArray(11) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E69:E70")
    Set rArray(12) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E72")
    Set rArray(13) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E83:E87")
    Set rArray(14) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E89:E91")
    Set rArray(15) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E93:E95")
    Set rArray(16) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E99:E100")
    Set rArray(17) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E102:E103")
    Set rArray(18) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E106")
    Set rArray(19) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E111:E118")
    Set rArray(20) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E123:E124")
    Set rArray(21) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E126:E130")
    Set rArray(22) = Sheets("LMA").Range("E133:E135")
    
'Set ranges for calc info to be pasted in

    Set tArray(1) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C30")
    Set tArray(2) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C37")
    Set tArray(3) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C41")
    Set tArray(4) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C43")
    Set tArray(5) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C47")
    Set tArray(6) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C52")
    Set tArray(7) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C54")
    Set tArray(8) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C56")
    Set tArray(9) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C59")
    Set tArray(10) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C64")
    Set tArray(11) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C69")
    Set tArray(12) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C72")
    Set tArray(13) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C83")
    Set tArray(14) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C89")
    Set tArray(15) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C93")
    Set tArray(16) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C99")
    Set tArray(17) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C102")
    Set tArray(18) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C106")
    Set tArray(19) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C111")
    Set tArray(20) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C123")
    Set tArray(21) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C126")
    Set tArray(22) = Sheets("LMA").Range("C133")
    
'Copy paste loop thru ranges
    
    Dim i, j As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 22
    rArray(i).Copy
    j = 0
        Do Until Sheets("LMA").Cells(21 + j, 21).Value = ""
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    tArray(i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Next
    


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Single-Column Areas

- Note that this is my choice which requires referencing the worksheet.
- If the code will always be in the workbook containing the worksheet, only a few lines need to be rearranged (modified) to call it e.g. with `CopyColumns "LMA", 5, 3`, or if it is worksheet-specific, with a simple `CopyColumns 5, 3`. Have a think and let me know.

**Utilization**

```vb
Sub CopyColumnsTEST()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("LMA")
    
    CopyColumns ws, "E", "C"
    'or equivalently:
    'CopyColumns ws, 5, 3
    
End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub CopyColumns( _
         ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
         ByVal SourceColumn As Variant, _
         ByVal DestinationColumn As Variant)
         
    Dim RowsAddress As String: RowsAddress _
        = "30:34,37:39,41:41,43:44,47:50,52:52," _
        & "54:54,56:57,59:60,64:66,69:70,72:72," _
        & "83:87,89:91,93:95,99:100,102:103,106:106," _
        & "111:118,123:124,126:130,133:135"
        
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = ws.Range(RowsAddress)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(rrg, ws.Columns(SourceColumn))
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Intersect(rrg, ws.Columns(DestinationColumn))
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To srg.Areas.Count
        drg.Areas(n).Value = srg.Areas(n).Value
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great, but for this part of the code: 

CopyColumns ws, "E", "C"
    'or equivalently:
    'CopyColumns ws, 5, 3

It will not always be "E" (or 5). This is a variable I want the user to be able to select from within the worksheet so the code does not need to be changed each time.  Is this possible? I was thinking of having the user enter an "x" in a single cell in range E26:AW26. The code looks for that "x", lets say it is in H26, the above code would change the "E" to "H" (or 8).

Comment: I have actually figured out how to do this by using a find function. The below seems to work for me. 
Sub CopyColumnsTEST()
    
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim rngBox As Range
    Dim rngCol As Range
    Set rngBox = Range("26:26")
    Set rngX = rngBox.find("x")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("LMA")
    
    CopyColumns ws, rngX.Column, "C"
    
End Sub

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing. I didn't realize that the last parameter is fixed. Similarly, you could use e.g. `Dim Index as Variant: Index = Application.Match("x", rngBox, 0)` and test its result with `If IsNumeric(Index) Then` and use `Index` as the column (the 2nd parameter): `CopyColumns ws, Index, "C"`.

Comment: Once the data is pasted into Column C, it is copied and pasted to another sheet. Do you know the best way to loop my current code so the user can place multiple "x" and the code would run for each one and copy paste one after the other in the other sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try another range syntax:

```
Dim columnRef as Long:  columnRef = 5
'Dim columnRef as String:  columnRef = "E"
'Dim columnRef as Long:  columnRef = Selection.Column
With Sheets("LMA")
    .Range( .Cells( 1, columnRef), .Cells( 2, columnRef))
End With
```

You can use `columnRef` as a reference for your specific column.

---

As for pulling the `Selection.Column`, you have a lot of ways to do that, where you will have to give your specific example.  Each will have different associated code.

Comment: Its not the range I am having issue with, it is just the column reference E that needs to be dynamic or a variable. I think VB below may be onto something.

Comment: @DrSch that's exactly what i'm showing generic examples of.  `columnRef` is a variable that can be dynamically assigned, hence the option for `columnRef = Selection.Column`.  Depending on how you want to assign said column depends on what you want to do.  The choice for how to represent the range may make it easier to assess and utilize.